# About Bonus Power Point for Psionics, do they stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The formula for Bonus Power Points is.

modifier × your manifester level x 1/2
Ex: Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 1 X 1/2 = 2PP

Does the bonus PP per level stack?

Ex: Wis 18(+4)
Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 1 X 1/2 = 2PP

Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 2 X 1/2 = 4PP

Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 3 X 1/2 = 6PP

Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 4 X 1/2 = 8PP

Wis 18(+4) = 4 X Lv 5 X 1/2 = 10PP

---

Total bonus PP at Lv 5 = 30

Answer (score 4):

## No

Your total bonus power points at a given level is equal to 1/2 your manifester level times your manifesting ability modifier.

As a tip, when reading a table in Pathfinder, 99% of the time, you're looking at the cumulative sum at a given level. There are occasional, very rare exceptions, but they're called out when they happen.

Comment: It’s worth noting that Forrestfire was, for a time, an editor at Dreamscarred Press, who publishes the psionics rules for Pathfinder.